# Create flatpak runtime with specified /usr and similar dirs

Tags: package-management, flatpak, sandbox

What I'm trying to build is a flatpak runtime that will use `/usr` as symlink to say `/my/usr` or the host `/usr`. That way existing containers and host runtime can be used for apps that are either not maintained well as flatpaks or the flatpak runtimes it depends on are just too huge and probably not needed (two copies of same libs, say). [1](https://ludocode.com/blog/flatpak-is-not-the-future)

As building runtimes is "discouraged", there are little documentation and only tools to build for certain environments (fedora, apertis). So where can I find a relevant doc for this? Does a similar project already exist?

PS: using flatpak for these cases has nothing to do with portability, but the sandbox is a great advantage here.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the answer you were looking for but the only guide I found was for creating a base runtime for Arch

https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Flatpak

From section 4:

### Creating a custom base runtime

You can create a custom Arch-based base runtime and base SDK for Flatpak using pacman. You can then use it for building and packaging applications. This is an alternative for personal use to the default `org.freedesktop.BasePlatform` and `org.freedesktop.BaseSdk` runtimes.

In addition to flatpak, you need to have installed fakeroot and for pacman hooks support also fakechroot.

First, start by creating a directory for building the runtime and possibly applications.

```
$ mkdir myflatpakbuilddir
$ cd myflatpakbuilddir
```

You can then prepare a directory for building the runtime base platform. The files subdirectory will contain what will later be the `/usr` directory in the sandbox. Therefore you will need to create symbolic links so the default `/usr/share` etc. from Arch can still be accessed at the usual path.

```
$ mkdir -p myruntime/files/var/lib/pacman
$ touch myruntime/files/.ref
$ ln -s /usr/usr/share myruntime/files/share
$ ln -s /usr/usr/include myruntime/files/include
$ ln -s /usr/usr/local myruntime/files/local
```

Make your host OS fonts available to the Arch runtime:

```
$ mkdir -p myruntime/files/usr/share/fonts
$ ln -s /run/host/fonts myruntime/files/usr/share/fonts/flatpakhostfonts
```

You need and may want to adapt your `pacman.conf` before installing packages to the runtime. Copy `/etc/pacman.conf` to your build directory and then make the following changes:

- Remove the `CheckSpace` option so pacman will not complain about errors finding the root filesystem for checking disk space.
- Remove any undesired custom repositories and `IgnorePkg`, `IgnoreGroup`, `NoUpgrade` and `NoExtract` settings that are needed only for the host system.

Now install the packages for the runtime.

```
$ fakechroot fakeroot pacman -Syu --root myruntime/files --dbpath myruntime/files/var/lib/pacman --config pacman.conf base
$ mv pacman.conf myruntime/files/etc/pacman.conf
```

Set up the [locales](/title/Locale) to be used by editing `myruntime/files/etc/locale.gen`. Then regenerate the runtime’s locales.

```
$ fakechroot chroot myruntime/files locale-gen
```

The base SDK can be created from the base runtime with added applications needed for building packages and running pacman.

```
$ cp -r myruntime mysdk
$ fakechroot fakeroot pacman -S --root mysdk/files --dbpath mysdk/files/var/lib/pacman --config mysdk/files/etc/pacman.conf base-devel fakeroot fakechroot --needed
```

Insert metadata about runtime and SDK.

*myruntime*/metadata

```
[Runtime]
name=org.mydomain.BasePlatform
runtime=org.mydomain.BasePlatform/x86_64/2016-06-26
sdk=org.mydomain.BaseSdk/x86_64/2016-06-26
```

mysdk/metadata

```
[Runtime]
name=org.mydomain.BaseSdk
runtime=org.mydomain.BasePlatform/x86_64/2016-06-26
sdk=org.mydomain.BaseSdk/x86_64/2016-06-26
```

Add base runtime and SDK to a local repository in the current directory. You may want to give them appropriate commit messages such as “My Arch base runtime” and “My Arch base SDK”.

```
$ ostree init --mode archive-z2 --repo=.
$ EDITOR="nano -w" ostree commit -b runtime/org.mydomain.BasePlatform/x86_64/2016-06-26 --tree=dir=myruntime
$ EDITOR="nano -w" ostree commit -b runtime/org.mydomain.BaseSdk/x86_64/2016-06-26 --tree=dir=mysdk
$ ostree summary -u
```

Install the runtime and SDK.

```
$ flatpak remote-add --user --no-gpg-verify myarchos file://$(pwd)
$ flatpak install --user myarchos org.mydomain.BasePlatform 2016-06-26
$ flatpak install --user myarchos org.mydomain.BaseSdk 2016-06-26
```